# Brown Corpus Doesn't Yield Results with HMM and TnT taggers

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, trigram

The most dynamic corpus with respect to POS taggers is the ***treebank corpus*** . However the Brown Corpus Just refuses to yield results with both HMM and TnT taggers. Any explanation on that?

```
size = int(len(brown.tagged_sents())*0.9)
train = brown.tagged_sents()[:size]
test = brown.tagged_sents()[size:]
trainer = hmm.HiddenMarkovModelTrainer()
tagger = trainer.train_supervised(train)
print(tagger.evaluate(test))

tnt_tagger = tnt.TnT()
tnt_tagger.train(train)
print(tnt_tagger.evaluate(test))
```

Comment: Hard to explain without any code to speak of.

Comment: size = int(len(brown.tagged_sents())*0.9)
    train = brown.tagged_sents()[:size]
    test = brown.tagged_sents()[size:]
    trainer = hmm.HiddenMarkovModelTrainer()
    tagger = trainer.train_supervised(train)
    print(tagger.evaluate(test))

Comment: Thanks. Please put it in your question and format it as a code block.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct-- for the `hmm` tagger at least. You don't say what "just refuses to yield results" really means, but you probably mean that it seems to hang? It doesn't. You must realize that training a model with these algorithms takes a long time, and on top of that the nltk is not generally designed for speed-- its main focus is educational.

Test your code with a 100-sentence training set and you should be able to confirm that it works. (You'll still have to wait a little bit).

```
train = brown.tagged_sents()[:100]
test = brown.tagged_sents()[100:200]
```

The TnT code is another matter, since it does not support unknown words on its own. See `help(tnt)` and take it from there.